# STL container objects by value versus by reference

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I think I have some misunderstanding of how to move STL container
objects by value versus by reference. Specifically, I don't understand
why the following program crashes:

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <cstdio>

class Value {
public:
  int x, y;
  Value(int a, int b) { x = a; y = b; }
};

class Test {
public:
  Test(int x, int y) { values.insert(new Value(x, y)); }
  void add(int x, int y) { values.insert(new Value(x, y)); }
  std::set<Value *> getValues() { return values; }
private:
  std::set<Value *> values;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<Test> Ts;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Test t(0, 0);
    t.add(i, 0);
    Ts.push_back(t);
  }
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (std::set<Value *>::iterator it = Ts.at(i).getValues().begin(), ite = Ts.at(i).getValues().end(); it != ite; ++it) {
      Value *v = *it;
      printf("(%d, %d) ", v->x, v->y);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This program segfaults in the second for loop (trying to print the
values in the `Ts` vector). However, if you change the initial loop to:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  Ts.push_back(Test(0, 0));
}
```

Then the program executes fine. Furthermore, if you take the first
program (crashing) and change the print loop to:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  std::set<Value *> values = Ts.at(i).getValues();
  for (std::set<Value *>::iterator it = values.begin(), ite = values.end(); it != ite; ++it) {
    Value *v = *it;
    printf("(%d, %d) ", v->x, v->y);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Then the program does not crash.

I would like to understand what is causing these crashes, and what the differences between the programs are.

Comment: Are you aware that your program is leaking memory? There is absolutely no reason to use `new` in the `Test` class.

Comment: @pmr Yes. This is a reduced test-case version of my larger program, which properly frees the values later.

Comment: Besides the part where you're leaking memory, you are also making several copies of the `values` set in your for-loop, because `getValues()` returns a copy. This could be why the iterator is reaching a bad position in memory, leading to a segmentation fault.

Comment: @E_net4 At the very least, those iterators may not be compared, they point to different objects (data structures). The end of the range `it` points into is *not* `ite`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem that I seem to find here is summed up in two lines of your code:

```
std::set<Value *> getValues() { return values; }
```

This member function returns a copy of your set of pointers.

```
for (std::set<Value *>::iterator it = Ts.at(i).getValues().begin(), ite = Ts.at(i).getValues().end(); it != ite; ++it)
```

With the same line of logic, this instruction creates two sets in the initialization phase. `ite` will not be the end iterator of the expected set, but rather the end pointer of another, freshly created container. The consequence is that doing `it != ite` will most likely not be reached before `it` points to other unexpected positions in memory.

Your correction works because now you are always dealing with iterators from the same set. A copy still happens here, but it's a safe one in this case. Also note that all copies are shallow, because you are storing raw pointers.

```
std::set<Value *> values = Ts.at(i).getValues(); // get copy of set
for (std::set<Value *>::iterator it = values.begin(), ite = values.end(); it != ite; ++it) { // using iterators from the same set, this is OK
```

Comment: Thanks, this make sense. Can you also explain why the first "fix" worked? I.e. leaving the loop iterators alone, but changing the way the items are added to the `Ts` vector? Was it just luck?

Comment: I've been analysing that as well, but found no plausible reasons for that to work. The only difference seems to be having sets with 1 element rather than 2. Why everything worked in that first "fix" still looks like a masqueraded case of undefined behaviour.